# What do I use to read from STDIN/write to STDOUT of a child process?

Tags: windows, perl

I have an executable which reads from STDIN and output goes to STDOUT.

I need a Perl script which will fork this executable as a child and write to STDIN of that child process and read from the STDOUT.

This is required for Windows. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[perlfaq8 *How can I open a pipe both to and from a command?*](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_can_I_open_a_pip)

Comment: `perldoc -q` should be advertised more.

Answer (score 3):

The prescribed solution is the [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Open2) module, but the code below may hang on Windows.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use IPC::Open2;

my $pid = open2 my $out, my $in, "./myfilter.exe";
die "$0: open2: $!" unless defined $pid;

print $in "$_\n" for qw/ foo bar baz /;
close $in or warn "$0: close: $!";

while (<$out>) {
  chomp;
  print "Parent: [$_]\n";
}

close $out or warn "$0: close: $!";
```

Comment: It seems there is no clean solution for Windows.

Comment: Awesome! Now I can sign a xml using xmlsec1 without write any file. Thanks