# Perl How to exit from child script which does a telnet?

Tags: perl, telnet, exit

I have a script which executes few commands and then telnets to machine. Now I need to call this script from another perl script.

```
$result = `some_script.pl`;
```

The script some_script.pl executes successfully but I am not able to exit from the main script as the script waits at the telnet prompt.

I also need to capture the exit status of the script in order to make sure that some_script.pl executed successfully.

I cannot modify some_script.pl.

Is there some way by which I can issue quit after the some_script.pl is executed successfully?

Comment: Why does it telnet to a machine? Does it run anything once it has telnet-ed to it?

Comment: `system('some_script.pl &');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this 'magic' close the standard in/out/err and may let your program finish.

$result = `some_script.pl >&- 2>&- <&-';

Otherwise you could use open2 and expect to watch for a specific string (like Done!) in your program output and close it when done.

http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way you are actually executing your perl script with a "backtick" call to the system.
I suggest you actually fork (or something equivalent) and run the program in a more controlled manner.

```
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
my $pid = fork();
if($pid) { # on the parent proc, $pid will point to the child
  waitpid($pid); # wait for the child to finish      
} else { # this is the child, where we want to run the telnet
  exec 'some_script.pl'; # this child will now "become" some_script.pl
}
```

Since I don't know how some_script.pl actually works, I cannot really help you more here.  But for example, if all you need to do is print "quit" on the command line of some_script.pl you could use [IPC::Open2](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/ext/IPC-Open2/lib/IPC/Open2.pm) like suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493437/what-do-i-use-to-read-from-stdin-write-to-stdout-of-a-child-process).  Doing something like:

```
use IPC::Open2;

$pid = open2(\*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_IN, 'some_script.pl');
print CHLD_IN "quit\n";
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

You do need to tweak this a little, but the idea should solve your problem.